# My computer has two php folders so I either can't connect to SQL Server or install Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, composer-php

I spent two days setting up my PHP connection to SQL Server.

I downloaded the drivers, added them to the C:\Program Files\php\ext folder (as indicated by phpinfo()). Then I modified the php.ini file to add those extensions. Then I went to services and restarted "SQL Server EXPRESS". Nothing worked until I found that PHP is also installed in another folder on my PC: C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v8.0. So I added the drivers there too and changed the php.ini file and restarted the SQL Server EXPRESS service (is that what they mean with restarting your web server?). The phpinfo() page said:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:  no value
Loaded Configuration File:          C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\v8.0\php.ini
```

and there was no section "sqlsserver". I gave up and the next day it magically worked. The phpinfo had a "sqlserver" section and the connection to my database no longer said "Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()".

Now, I had to download Laravel for my course, and install Composer. When doing so, it was unable to install when I had C:\Program Files\iis express\PHP\ as my PATH and it asked me if I wanted to make C:\Program Files\php\ my PATH instead. So I clicked yes, and the installation was successful.

Laravel works, however now my database connections with SQL Server don't work anymore! I get the same old "Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()" error, and my phpinfo() now says

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Program Files\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

and there is no longer a "sqlsserver" section on the page.

I have tried everything in StackOverflow articles, such as removing the semicolon in the php.ini extension, including the full address in the extensions in the php.ini file, including the extensions of the other php folder into this php.ini file, restarting SQL Server service, etc. But nothing works. I also don't know how to reset the old PHP folder back into the PATH variable.

My connection code is:

```
$con = sqlsrv_connect( 'localhost' ,
    [ 'Database' => 'sample_db' ,
        'UID' => 'sample_user' ,
        'PWD' => 'sample_password' ]
    );

//Print error message if the database doesn't connect

if ($con === false ){
    echo 'Failed to connect to db: ' . sqlsrv_errors()[ 0 ][ 'message' ];
    exit ();
}
```

How can I have these two php folder on my computer both work, the one for my PHP SQL Server database connection, and the other for my Laravel programme to run? Has anyone else had this issue and I so, what worked for you?

Comment: *"SQL Server EXPRESS service (is that what they mean with restarting your web server?)"* No not at all... SQL Server Express is the **R**elational **D**ata**b**ase **M**anagement **S**oftware (RDBMS) it has *nothing* to do with hosting web sites, apart from that is where the data used by your website might be (i.e. Users, Posts, etc). Your Web Server program is the program used to host the web sites. For example Tomcat, Apache, Internet Information Services (IIS), Nginx, to name a few. From your configuration file, looks like you are using IIS, so you should have restarted *that*.

Comment: Please share more details. How is this related to Composer?

Comment: @NicoHaase It is related to Composer because everything was working before I installed Composer. While installing Composer, it suggested I change the php.ini file in my PATH. After that, everything stopped working.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for explaining! Do you know how I restart IIS? It is not listed in 'services' like the others are.

Comment: I have very little exposure to IIS, @timi_gun . I sure if you google "Restart IIS Web site" you'll find out how.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this by changing the PATH back to the php folder instead of the iis/php folder. I was worried that would break my Laravel now, but it didn't.